# Computation of tensor elements

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, vector-fields

Suppose the matrix of linear map $T:E \to F$ in basis of $E$ and $F$ be like $T^{j}_{i}$; I want to compute the the tensorian elements of  $T_{*}(X)$ and $T^{*}(W)$ for $X \in \otimes^{k} E$ and $W \in \otimes_{k}F$.

If $T:E \to F$ be linear map then for every :
\begin{align}
u_1 \otimes ... \otimes u_K \in \otimes^kE
\end{align}
We put :

\begin{align}
T(X)= T_{*}(X)=T(u_1) \otimes ... \otimes T(u_k) \in \otimes^kF
\end{align}
\begin{align}
T_{*}: \otimes^kE \to \otimes^kF
\end{align}
and $T^{t}= T^{*}:F^{*} \to E^{*}$ which $\beta \mapsto \beta \circ T$ and $T^{*} : \otimes_k F \to \otimes_k E$ which $T^{*}(\beta^1 \otimes ... \otimes \beta^k) = T^{*}(\beta^1) \otimes ... \otimes T^{*}(\beta^k)$

Could anyone hint me ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to compute the *matrix* of $T_*$ and $T^*$? Also, could you clarify what exactly $T_*$ and $T^*$ refer to in this context?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I made an edit on my post according your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, I'm still wondering about the first question. What exactly do you mean by "computing" the linear map?

Comment: If you are interested in computing the matrices of these maps, then the matrix of $T_*$ (relative to a certain bases of $\bigotimes^k E$ and $\bigotimes^k F$ "induced" by those of $E$ and $F$) will be the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the matrix of $T$ with itself. Correspondingly, the matrix of $T^*$ (relative to the dual bases) will be the transpose of the matrix of $T_*$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm looking forward to computing the coeficients of tensor

Comment: In the context with which I am familiar, $\bigotimes^k E$ and $\bigotimes^k F$ are [vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), which means that the coefficients of $T_*$ and $T^*$ would form a matrix. However, from your response to my comment it sounds like you are not expecting a matrix. What exactly is the "shape" of the tensors $T_*$ and $T^*$ as you are using them?

Comment: Exactly, I mean how the shape of $T_{*}$ and $T^{*} $are.